# Rick Text Editing: Advanced options for Non-Technical Clients

Tags: content-management-system, tinymce, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

We've for years been struggling on what Rich Text Editor to use for our clients. The large share of our client request concern issues with the editor, and we have summarized the causes to be 90% of the time a combination of the following:

- Client does not understand anything of HTML and can only use what the editor provides.
- Client wants to do "advanced stuff" like specifically formatted footers under photos (we create classes for these kinds of requests), combined with floating boxes and special fonts.
- Client copies stuff from other places - especially Word.
- Images go into the article as well.

From a client-perspective, these are not overly crazy things, and I want to be able to actually support this. However, after so many years and trying several editors (mainly CKEditor and TinyMCE) we always end up with continuous requests because things go wrong. We generally fix it manually or hack up things in the editor, but I am really interested if this is normal. Are there Rich Text Editors that can do the above easily and without causing much trouble? Do your clients also have problems with these things?

Comment: Apologies for using a comment but I couldn't see how to contact @plua directly. The company I work (Ephox) makes a Rich Text editor (EditLive) that may be worth considering as it does alot of what you listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich text editing on the web is a complex problem. Effectively, vendors that sell products like ckeditor and tinyMCE are restricted by what the browsers provide in terms of a rich text editing engine.

Each editor is merely an iframed document with contentEditable set to true. This exposes the underlying RTE engine of the browser, including all the quirks and implementation specifics of that browser.

Bottom line is, you are never going to achieve a word like experience in the browser with the current state of browsers. Period. Your clients will always have an unrealistic expectation of rich text editing on the web.

Our job is to mitigate the problems through managing expectations. They need to know that this is the web, not Word. They need to know that most things will work OK, and some will work poorly. They also need to know that things are never going to be consistent across all browsers.

Comment: Besides that, no matter how you create the HTML, a web page isn't a Word document or a PDF, the web isn't meant to behave the same way and the visitors will use different browsers, different screens... IE10 introduces new CSS to enable text flowing around an image, but until then your clients won't be able to get that behavior with any editor for the web. And so on...

Comment: +1 steve_c educating the end users on the "limitations" of HTML when trying to edit documents on the web is crucial. I'm always amazed Alfonso how many people want print capabilities (like pages) in RTEs.